# How do I get text width and height in Swing/AWT?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a game engine based on Java Swing and I wonder if I can get the text width/height.

Say, what I have is:

- the text string
- the font and text size (the `Font` object)

What I've done is:

- `g.drawString(...)`

What I want to know is:

- the width/height of the text that displayed on the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphics returns [FontMetrics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) that have method getStringBounds (and other usefull methods):

```
Rectangle2D r = graphics.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(string, graphics);
```

With `r` you can for example render background for text and then render text.